# How to use SessionID using PostMan Rest client

Tags: api, postman

Getting "SessionId" from response of user logged in session using POSTMAN REST client.

How to use the sessionId for other API calls of GET request?

Comment: Are you wanting to use something from the response body or do you need to access the value of a "_session_id" cookie? Cookies require extra a bit of extra work: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/capture

Answer (score 3):

Making a few assumptions about your data structure, store it as a variable:

```
//parse the response body as JSON 
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);

//create a global variable that can be reused in another call
postman.setGlobalVariable("sessionId", data.SessionId")
```

To use in a call to another endpoint:

http://www.example.com/{{sessionId}}